# KeyPass integration for Chrome

Tags: windows, chrome, security, password-manager

I'm looking for an extension to chrome that integrates with a KeyPass instance. I would like the extension to meet these requirements,

- Gratis
- Works on Windows 10
- Works with the KeyPass application itself (does not directly go off of a database file, the extension "[CKP - KeePass integration for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ckp-keepass-integration-f/lnfepbjehgokldcaljagbmchhnaaogpc)" does *not* meet this requirement)
- Can automatically (or with a click or two) create a new entry based on logging into a website
- Can automatically (or with a click or two) look up and log into a website using existing credentials based on the website field of an entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An application that meets all of these requirements is chromeIPass. It's very simple and easy to use but to install it, you need to install an addon, KeePassHttp, for KeyPass itself and then integrate it with chromeIPass. It is free and works on windows 10. It integrates nicely with the KeyPass instance itself. It automatically creates new or updates entries based off of logging into websites and if it has credentials for a site, it will automatically log you into the site for you. This extension is also available for FireFox as well.

## [chromeIPass](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromeipass/ompiailgknfdndiefoaoiligalphfdae) ([free](https://github.com/pfn/passifox))

> extensions for the browsers Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome to integrate KeePass as password manager into these browsers.
>
> #### Features
>
> - returns all matching entries for a given URL
> - updates entries
> - secure exchange of entries
> - notifies user if entries are delivered
> - user can allow or deny access to single entries
> - works only if the database is unlocked
> - request for unlocking the database if it is locked while connecting
> - searches in all opened databases (if user activates this feature)
> - Whenever events occur, the user is prompted either by tray notification or requesting interaction (allow/deny/remember).
>
> [image: chromeIPass windows]